# How can I control the number of threads?

Tags: raku

```
#The @url.elems >= 10000
    for @url -> $url {
       start {
          say $url;
          sleep(1);
       }
    }
```

How can I control the number of threads?

Answer (score 12):

Before answering the question: the code you show loses the `Promise` returned by `start`.  You probably want:

```
await do for @url -> $url {
   start {
      say $url;
      sleep(1);
   }
}
```

This will wait until all of the start blocks have completed.

To get back to your question: the environment variable `RAKUDO_MAX_THREADS` can be set before running your program to the maximum number of threads that will be created (default is 16).

Another approach that also works at runtime is to create a new ThreadPoolScheduler object dynamically:

```
my $*SCHEDULER = ThreadPoolScheduler.new(max_threads => 32);
```

Any threaded code that can see this version of `$*SCHEDULER` will now use this scheduler which has 32 threads available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bunch of jobs in an array and want to work through them in parallel, take a look at [hyper](https://docs.raku.org/routine/hyper) and [race](https://docs.raku.org/routine/race).  (Currently marked as 'experimental', they will work even better in the next major release.)

With them, you can (potentially) control the parallelism with the 'batch' and 'degree' parameters.

```
@url.race(:batch(1),:degree(4)).map(-> $url {
    say $url;
    sleep(1);
});
```

They are, of course, subject to the overall thread limits of the ThreadPoolScheduler.

Comment: @firecat Be careful with `race` and `hyper`. They are really fun to use. However, if you use them in production, be sure to have good tests for your code. There are multiple bugs with them (e.g. [126597](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=126597), [129234](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=129234), [127365](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127365), and [130576](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130576) ).

Comment: Please note that all of these problems have been resolved since October 2017 with the re-implementation of the `race` and `hyper` logic.